# FTP. Скопировать структуру папок

Tags: python, python-3.x, рекурсия, ftp, ftp-сервер

Задание связано с ftp сервером. Нужно создать структуру папок на сервере такую же, как в определенной
папке локального диска (такие же папки, с таким же вложением). Файлы
можно игнорировать.

Вот функция makedirs для копирования структуры:

```
def makedirs(sock, path, is_first):
    if is_first == 1:
        print('Создаём папку ' + path)
        send_data(sock, f'mkd {path[3:]}')
        sock.recv(4096)
        send_data(sock, f'cwd {path[3:]}')
    else:
        send_data(sock, f'mkd {path}')
        sock.recv(4096)
        send_data(sock, f'cwd {path}')
    sock.recv(4096)
    for sub in os.listdir(path):
        sub_path = os.path.join(path, sub)
        print('Создаём папку ' + sub_path)
        send_data(sock, f'mkd {sub}')
        sock.recv(4096)
        send_data(sock, f'cwd {sub}')
        sock.recv(4096)
        makedirs(sock, sub_path, 0)
        if is_first == 1:
            send_data(sock, f"cwd /{path[3:]}")
        else:
            send_data(sock, f"cwd /{path}")
        sock.recv(4096)
        #send_data(sock, f"cwd {sub}")
```

**sock** - сокет, с помощью которого я подключился к ftp серверу.

**path** - путь до папки, структура которой будет копироваться (например C:\dirtest)

**is_first** - проверка на первый запуск функции (чтобы отбросить C:)

Я создаю папку, отправляя серверу команду 'mkd %имя_папки%' с помощью функции send_data, а потом перехожу в неё с помощью cwd. Далее в цикле с помощью os.listdir я начинаю перебор подпапок, создаю, перехожу, а потом рекурсивно запускаю функцию makedirs для неё и после завершения перехожу обратно в директорию, из которой запустил поиск.

По итогу должна получиться структура типа такой:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но почему-то создаётся "списком":

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Помогите найти ошибку

Answer (score 0):

Починил, всё работает

```
def makedirs(sock, path, is_first):
    if is_first == 1:
        print('Создаём папку ' + path)
        send_data(sock, f'mkd {path[3:]}')
        sock.recv(4096)
        send_data(sock, f'cwd {path[3:]}')
        sock.recv(4096)
    for sub in os.listdir(path):
        sub_path = os.path.join(path, sub)
        print('Создаём папку ' + sub_path)
        send_data(sock, f'mkd {sub}')
        sock.recv(4096)
        send_data(sock, f'cwd {sub}')
        sock.recv(4096)
        makedirs(sock, sub_path, 0)
        if is_first == 1:
            send_data(sock, f"cwd /test/{path[3:]}")
        else:
            send_data(sock, f"cwd /test/{path[3:]}")
        sock.recv(4096)
```

UPD. Для тех, у кого будет похожая задача - попробуйте использовать **CDUP**. Эта команда сразу перекидывает вас в родительскую папку. Жаль, что поздно узнал про неё, наверно с ней пришлось бы меньше шаманить